# Vertical Spacing Between Images In HTML Email

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm working on HTML email template.
I created it with a few nested tables.
I found that there are spaces to the right of the images in Outlook.
So I tried to fix this, but it doesn't fix.
Finally I create a simple template depending on colored images which I create to make it possible identifying the table cells.

Here's my code (Please copy it and test on Outlook):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>HTML Email Design Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <style media="all" type="text/css">
    table td {
   border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    img { padding: 0; margin: 0; display:block;}
    </style>
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#cccccc">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" height="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #000000;">
      <tr>
       <td align="center" style="padding: 40px 0 40px 0; font-size: 26px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        First Row
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <table width="600" height="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#08336d">
         <tr>
          <td width="300" height="600">
           <img src="http://2a-web.com/email/test/images/img-01.jpg" width="300px" height="600px" border="0" style="display:block; line-height:0; font-size:0;"/>
          </td>
          <td width="300" height="600">
           <table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
             <td width="300" height="300">
              <img src="http://2a-web.com/email/test/images/img-02.jpg" width="300px" height="300px" border="0" style="display:block; line-height:0; font-size:0;"/>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td width="300" height="300">
              <table width="300" height="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tr>
                <td width="150" height="300">
                 <img src="http://2a-web.com/email/test/images/img-03.jpg" width="150px" height="300px" border="0" style="display:block; line-height:0; font-size:0;"/>
                </td>
                <td width="150" height="300" bgcolor="#ffc33c">
                 <table width="150" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td width="150" height="150">
                    <img src="http://2a-web.com/email/test/images/img-04.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" border="0" style="display:block; line-height:0; font-size:0;"/>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td width="150" height="150" bgcolor="#16b512">
                    <table width="150" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tr>
                      <td width="75" height="150">
                       <img src="http://2a-web.com/email/test/images/img-05.jpg" width="75px" height="150px" border="0" style="display:block; line-height:0; font-size:0;"/>
                      </td>
                      <td width="75" height="150">
                       <img src="http://2a-web.com/email/test/images/img-06.jpg" width="75px" height="150px" border="0" style="display:block; line-height:0; font-size:0;"/>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="center" style="padding: 40px 0 40px 0; font-size: 26px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
        Third Row
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

So, how can I remove the gap between cells ?

I'm appreciating your help.

Comment: `table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }`

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look and testing in outlook with your provided HTML, I believe I know what you are experiencing, and it has to due with images.

First off, all the images in your HTML are not available so I had to test with my own images. These is where, I noticed the issue. My images were causing to email to expand beyond the specified width of 600. **This is because for outlook if you are going to use width and height attributes for a element, you leave off the px part, it's assumed**. I.E. 150 *NOT* 150px. As soon as I did everything snapped into place, no spacing issue.

I was only able to reproduce the vertical spacing/gapping on the right of the images after I forced one of the bottom images to have an exaggerated width, i.e. it's currently set to 150(same as the containing td), so I set it to 155. And bam! Got the spacing.

Meaning that your table layout/css is fine for the most part, outlook is probably freaking out because you are adding the px part. Either remove it or set the width/height with inline styling instead.